# Button doesn't navigate

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, navigation

this button that I am using to navigate from one fragment to the next doesn't do anything. I would appreciate any pointers to help.

TitleFragment.kt

```
class TitleFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        //Inflate the layout file
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_title, container, false)
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val btn : Button = view.findViewById(R.id.button)
        btn.setOnClickListener {
            view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_titleFragment_to_mainContent)
        }
    }
}
```

navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/titleFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/titleFragment"
        android:name="com.lbaron.flyingweather.TitleFragment"
        android:label="fragment_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_title" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_titleFragment_to_mainContent"
            app:destination="@id/mainContent" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:name="com.lbaron.flyingweather.MainContent"
        android:label="fragment_main_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main_content" />
</navigation>
```

As requested in a comment - here is the activity_main.xml with the Container View.
activity_main.xml

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/myNavHostFragment"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: What is the error? Are you the button is actually getting clicked?

Comment: No error - nothing happens when button is clicked

Comment: And you've verified that with the debugger?

Comment: Add a toast above the navigation inside the click listener; if that happened, then you are sure you have clicked the button.

Comment: @cutiko yep the toast displays but navigation doesn't happen

Comment: Does the activity or the fragment have a navigation container fragment?

Comment: @cutiko thanks, I've added the code for activity_main.xml in the question - I believe it contains what you are requesting